# how to configure hadoop 2.3.0 on windows 8?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cygwin

I try to configure hadoop 2.3.0 on windows but its give me

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf

and lots of other error like "winutils.exe","hadoop.dll messing" and "load main class" error.

Please help me to configure Hadoop on windows 8 machine.

I have installed 
JDK 1.7
cygwin64

Comment: See http://sundersinghc.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/running-hadoop-on-cygwin-in-windows-single-node-cluster/comment-page-1/

Comment: I try with this but same error

Answer (score 1):

If we directly take the binary distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.3 release and try to run it on Microsoft Windows, then we'll encounter ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path.

The binary distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.3 release does not contain some windows native components (like winutils.exe, hadoop.dll etc). These are required (not optional) to run Hadoop on Windows.

So you need to build windows native binary distribution of hadoop from source codes following "BUILD.txt" file located inside the source distribution of hadoop. You can follow the following posts (applicable for hadoop 2.3 as well) for step by step guide with screen shot

[Build, Install, Configure and Run Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 in Microsoft Windows OS](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os)

[ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps described in the below link which describes the installation of Hadoop 2.3.0 in a windows 8 machine.

http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

This works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing in windows:
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0-Win/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-chap2-singlenode.html

Prerrequisites:
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0-Win/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-getting-ready-2-3-2.HTML

Answer (score 0):

In the suggested tutorial above, the build instructions do not work for the most recent version of visual studio/.NET framework/Windows.

http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

First download the desired source version and ...

You do not need the windows 7 sdk/build will fail to create the binary. For windows 8, you can build the hadoop-2.5.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils solution and C:\hfds\hadoop-2.5.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native solutions in visual studio

Then download the binary version...

and place the output files in hadoop-2.5.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target\bin in the bin directory of the downloaded hadoop binary bin folder.

Then follow the remaining steps of the tutorial...